# AttributeError: 'ExtremeValueTheory' object has no attribute 'high_extremes'

Tags: python, oop, compiler-errors, attributeerror

```
from pyextremes import get_extremes
from pyextremes.plotting import plot_extremes


class ExtremeValueTheory:
    
    def __innit__(self,data):
        
        self.data = data
        self.low_extremes = get_extremes(data,'BM',extremes_type="low")
        self.high_extremes = get_extremes(data,'BM')
        self.high_peaks = get_extremes(data,'POT')
        self.low_peaks = get_extremes(data,'POT', extremes_type='low')
    
    def plot_block_maxima(self,data):
        
        plot_extremes(ts=data,
                      extremes = self.high_extremes,
                      extremes_method = 'BM',
                      extremes_type = 'high',
                      block_size = "90D"
                     )
        plt.show()
        
        return plot_extremes
    
    def plot_block_minima(self,data):
        
        plot_extremes(ts=data,
                      extremes = self.low_extremes,
                      extremes_method = 'BM',
                      extremes_type = 'low',
                      block_size = "90D"
                     )
        plt.show()
        
        return plot_extremes
    
    def get_high_extremes(self):
        
        return self.high_extreme
    
    def get_low_extremes(self):
        
        return self.low_extremes
    
    def plot_high_peaks_over_threshold(self,data):
        
        plot_extremes(ts=data,
                      extremes = self.high_peaks,
                      extremes_method = 'POT',
                      extremes_type = 'high',
                      block_size = "90D"
                     )
        plt.show()
        
        return plot_extremes
        
    def plot_low_peaks_over_threshold(self,data):
        
        plot_extremes(ts=data,
                     extremes = self.low_peaks,
                      extremes_method = 'POT',
                      extremes_type = 'low',
                      block_size = "90D"
                     )
        plt.show()
        
        return plot_extremes
    
    def get_high_peaks_over_threshold(self):
        
        return self.high_peaks
    
    def get_low_peaks_over_threshold(self):
        
        return self.low_peaks
```

and then I call the class and the function as follows:

```
ExtremeValueTheory().plot_block_maxima(final_df['high_yield_values'])
```

Edit: Here's the full traceback :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-9a91fd373865> in <module>
----> 1 ExtremeValueTheory().plot_block_maxima(final_df['high_yield_values'])

<ipython-input-26-2b670824557a> in plot_block_maxima(self, data)
     16 
     17         plot_extremes(ts=data,
---> 18                       extremes = self.high_extremes,
     19                       extremes_method = 'BM',
     20                       extremes_type = 'high',

AttributeError: 'ExtremeValueTheory' object has no attribute 'high_extremes'
```

I keep getting this attribute error whenever I am trying to call my function from the class, I am using self everywhere but it seems like python is not able to find the objects declared inside the **innit** method. I am using jupyter notebook to do all my coding. I think I am doing everything right but I still keep getting this attribute error

Comment: `__innit__` is not the same as `__init__`. Rename your initializer function.

Comment: Thank you, so it all came down to a stupid typo.